modification of Cochran's theorem
Assume we have $X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}$ are iid Standard Normal random variables. Next, let $Q = X^{T}AX$, where $A$ is a matrix with rank $r < n$. Next, assume we have
$$
Q = X^{T}B_{1}X + \dots + X^{T}B_{m}X
$$
such that $\sum_{i} rank(B_{i})$ = r. Do we then have a joint independence of $X^{T}B_{i}X$?
Also, what if $X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}$ are jointly Normal but not independent?

A fairly general version was given in Ravishanker & Dey's A First Course in Linear Model Theory (2001, 1st ed.) as Result 5.4.8:

Let $\mathbf{x}\sim N_k(\mu,\Sigma)$, $\mathbf{A}_i$ be $k\times k$ symmetric matrices with $r\left(\mathbf{A}_i\right)=r_i$, $i=1,2,\dots,n$, and let $\mathbf{A}=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{A}_i$ with $r(A)=r$. Then

$\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{A}_i\mathbf{x}\sim \chi^2\left(r_i,\frac12 \mu'\mathbf{A}_i\mu\right)$,
$\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{A}_i\mathbf{x}$ are pairwise independent, and
$\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\sim \chi^2\left(r,\frac12 \mu'\mathbf{A}\mu\right)$

if and only if

any two of the following are true:

$\mathbf{A}_i\Sigma$ is idempotent for all $i$,
$\mathbf{A}_i\Sigma\mathbf{A}_j=0$ for all $i<j$,
$\mathbf{A}\Sigma$ is idempotent, or


the following are true:

the above (4.3) is true, and
$r=\sum_{i=1}^n r_i$ holds, or


the following are true:

(4.3) is true, and
$\mathbf{A}_i\Sigma$ is idempotent for $i=1,2,\dots,n-1$ and $\mathbf{A}_n\Sigma$ is nonnegative definite.





PS1: Somehow I couldn't find this result in the 2nd version of this book.
PS2: This is the same as Theorem 5 in Section 2.5.c of Searle's Linear Models (1st edition) or Theorem 8a in the 2nd edition. Proofs were given in both books.
PS3: The theorem only holds when $\Sigma$ is non-singular. A parallel (but more general) theorem with possibly singular $\Sigma$ was presented as Theorem 5s in Searle's book (1st edition only). This points to Styan's 1970 Biometrika paper.

do not have access to this book. Are you sure that  $x'A_{I}x$ are only pairwise independent?..

That's what I suspect as well, but the book indeed stated "pairwise". No proof is given in the book.

@ABK Added some PS, in case that you have access to the more popular books by Searle.
